# I want to set new object in local storage

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
function addNote() {
    const givenTitle = document.getElementById('titleInput');
    const givenNote = document.getElementById('noteInput');
    
    let notesObj = []

    let myObj = {
        title: givenTitle.value,
        note: givenNote.value,
    }

    notesObj.push(myObj)

    localStorage.setItem('userNote',JSON.stringify(notesObj));
}
```

This code is everyTime changing the older value I want to get a new object in local storage

Comment: what your mean by `changing the older value`?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to describe.  This code creates an object, pushes that object onto an array, and writes that array to `localStorage`.  This [works as expected](https://jsfiddle.net/m4sfx2bc/) for me.  What specifically isn't working as expected?

Comment: If you want a new object, don't use the same key

Comment: When I enter a new value there should a new object with different values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you want to add note into your existing `localStorage` data so here you can check if there is `userNote` is already set before then take it or set an empty array,

```
let notesObj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("userNote")) || []
```

Your whole function would be like this,

```
function addNote() {
    const givenTitle = document.getElementById('titleInput');
    const givenNote = document.getElementById('noteInput');
    
    let notesObj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("userNote")) || []

    let myObj = {
        title: givenTitle.value,
        note: givenNote.value,
    }

    notesObj.push(myObj)

    localStorage.setItem('userNote',JSON.stringify(notesObj));
}
```